# About dimension of sheets of universal covering.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I need some clarification about the concept of $n-$sheet of a covering.
A little disclaimer before anything else: ll the definition and images I'll use in this post comes from the Hatcher book.
So a sheet of $\tilde{X}$ over $U$ is by definition the disjoint open sets of $\tilde{X}$ that get projected over the open set $U$.  So if we haver 3 disjoint set that get projected over $U$ that should be an $n-$sheet, doesn't it?
If we take this picture (page 56 of the atcher) those should be 2-map (1-2), 3-map (3-4-5-6), 4-map (7-8-9).
[image]

My problem begun at point 10. Is that an $\infty-$map?
And moreover, if we take he following two, are thoese $\infty-$map too?
[image]

Comment: Hatcher defines "sheets" as the cardinality of the set $p^{-1}(\{x\})$, where $p:\tilde{X}\to X$ is the covering map. Since $S^1\vee S^1$ is connected, you can simply count the preimage of the base point, which is infinite for (10), (12),  and (14), so they're *infinitely-sheeted covering spaces*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hatcher does not define what a sheet is, he only introduces the **number of sheets** of a covering $p : \tilde X \to X$ having a connected base $X$ as the common cardinality of the sets $p^{-1}(x)$ with $x \in X$.

If this cardinality is finite, say $n$, then he says that *$p$ has $n$ sheets* or *$p$ is an $n$-sheeted covering*.

Concerning the concept of **sheet** see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) or [Covering projections: What are the sheets over an evenly covered set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835771/covering-projections-what-are-the-sheets-over-an-evenly-covered-set)

To determine the number of sheets of the coverings depicted in Hatcher's diagrams recall that the two circles $S^1 \vee S^1$ are denoted by $a$ and $b$:

[image]

Then simply count the number of $a$'s or $b$'s occurring in the diagrams - this is the number of sheets.

- In (1) - (2) : $2$ sheets.
- In (3) - (6) : $3$ sheets.
- In (7) - (9) : $4$ sheets.
- In (10) - (11) : The sheet number is $\infty$ because the depicted objects are continued periodically ad infinitum to the left and to the right.
- In (12) - (14) : The sheet number is $\infty$ although it is not absolulety clear what the depicted objects *really* are. But I think we should take Hatcher's construction of a simply-connected covering space of  $S^1 \vee S^1$ on the following page as a model. This makes clear that there are infinitely many  line segments (getting smaller and smaller), and that at each crossing point in the parts looking like [image] two $a$'s and two $b$'s are meeting.